How to debug Okta SAML2 authentication issue in a React + Django application?
I'm integrating Okta SAML2 authentication into my React + Django application. However, despite not encountering any errors, when I attempt to access https://org.okta.com/app/org_lighthousedev_1/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8/sso/saml, it redirects me to https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/accounts/login/?next=/sso/saml/ instead of completing the SAML authentication flow.
I'm unsure how to debug this issue. I'm using djangosaml2==1.9.2 and djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.1. Could someone provide guidance or hints on what might be missing by reviewing the code snippet below?
These where I gave in okta request  for application creation
Single sign-on URL
https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/
Recipient URL
https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/
Destination URL
https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/
Audience URI (SP Entity ID)
https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/
Provide details by Okta Team
Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL:
https://org.okta.com/app/org_lighthousedev_1/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8/sso/saml
Identity Provider Issuer:
http://www.okta.com/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8
X.509 Certificate:okta.cert.txt
IDP metadata : IDP_Metadata.txt
Metadata.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://www.okta.com/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x22328" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"><md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificqate>MIIDojCCAoqgAqeqeqewIBqweqweqeAgIGAY9N9lbIMA0GsfsbfhsbfqwyegqyrqywqqCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGRMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG
..................
94nXBpszjEGkSxsAJ1HxEzDdVdDcTRa4YIVGPazKIaiNbNgCha8oGQVgJaXv2EkKFgqhcZeQ0Mfq
O7jSBH/M2U7QoTMhj0NhUCdy9ZGwt95TPhpJ8HZ6f0Ynqw+TmsPiRJyp8EVgjyv9weHgeuGk81k3
3JNrh0k2UpnGECHngkDJWGRseXr+zg==</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://org.okta.com/app/org_lighthousedev_1/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8/sso/saml"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://org.okta.com/app/org_lighthousedev_1/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8/sso/saml"/></md:IDPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>


setting.py
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from .saml2.saml_settings import SAML_CONFIG



load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['org.okta.com', 'lighthouse.corporate.org.com', 'dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com',
                 '127.0.0.1']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://org.okta.com', 'https://*.corporate.org.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_crontab',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'base_app.apps.BaseAppConfig',
    'document_app.apps.DocumentAppConfig',
    'djangosaml2',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # default
    'djangosaml2.backends.Saml2Backend',
)

# SAML2 related settings
SAML_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'saml_session'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

# Add SAML configurations
SAML_CONFIG = SAML_CONFIG

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',  # Manages various security aspects of the HTTP request-response cycle.
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',          # Manages Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), should follow SecurityMiddleware.
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  # Manages sessions across requests.
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',      # Provides various conveniences, such as URL normalization.
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',      # Adds CSRF protection.
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  # Associates users with requests using sessions.
    'djangosaml2.middleware.SamlSessionMiddleware',   # Integrates SAML sessions, must be after AuthenticationMiddleware.
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  # Enables cookie- and session-based messaging.
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',  # Provides clickjacking protection.
    'backend.middleware.AssumeRoleMiddleware',        # Custom middleware for assuming roles, specifics depend on its functionality.
    'base_app.middleware.profile_group_middleware',   # Custom middleware for managing user profiles or groups.
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'
SAML_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'saml_session'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),

    },
    "mongodb": {
        "ENGINE": "djongo",
        "NAME": os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_NAME'),
        "CLIENT": {
            "host": os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_HOST'),
            "port": int(os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_PORT')),
            # "username": os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            # "password": os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        },
        'TEST': {
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
    }
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',  # Adjust as needed
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}

LOGGING_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs')
if not os.path.exists(LOGGING_DIR):
    os.makedirs(LOGGING_DIR)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'light_house_backend.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'document_app': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'base_app': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['base_app.utils.routers.MyRouter', 'document_app.utils.routers.MyRouter']
FIXTURE_DIRS = ['base_app/fixtures/']

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

# Add the cronjob here
CRONJOBS = [


]

saml_settings.py
import saml2
from saml2.saml import NAMEID_FORMAT_EMAILADDRESS
from saml2.sigver import get_xmlsec_binary
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SAML_CONFIG = {
    'debug': True,
    'xmlsec_binary': get_xmlsec_binary(['/usr/bin/xmlsec1']),
    'entityid': 'http://www.okta.com/exk14dabkz9lmSTEq0x8',  # Updated to match the Audience URI
    'service': {
        'sp': {
            'name': 'Django SP',
            'endpoints': {
                'assertion_consumer_service': [
                    ('https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/', saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    # Updated to match the Single Sign-On URL
                ],
                'single_logout_service': [
                    ('https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/logout/', saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                    ('https://dev-lighthouse.corporate.org.com/sso/saml/logout/', saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    # Updated to match the Single Logout URLs
                ],
            },
            'allow_unsolicited': True,
            'authn_requests_signed': False,  # Okta metadata says 'WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"'
            'logout_requests_signed': True,
            'want_assertions_signed': True,
            'want_response_signed': True,
            'name_id_format': NAMEID_FORMAT_EMAILADDRESS,
        },
        
    },
    'metadata': {
        'local': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saml/dev_metadata.xml')],
    },
    'ca_certs': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saml/dev_okta.cert'),  # Path to Okta's certificate
}


urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from base_app.views.CustomSAML2View import CustomSAML2View



urlpatterns = [
    path('sso/saml/', CustomSAML2View.as_view(), name='saml2_acs'),
    path('saml2/', include('djangosaml2.urls')),
    ]


CustomSAML2View.py
    from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from djangosaml2.views import EchoAttributesView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import logging
# from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='OKTA_JWT.logs', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
# @method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch', login_url=None)  # Disables the redirection to the login page
class CustomSAML2View(EchoAttributesView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            logging.info('Inside CustomSAML2View')
            # Call the superclass post method, which handles the SAML assertion processing
            response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
            # Check if the user is authenticated after the SAML assertion is processed
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                # Generate JWT tokens for the authenticated user
                refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(request.user)
                logging.info(f'User {request.user.username} logged in with email {request.user.email}')
                # Return JWT to the client
                return JsonResponse({
                    'refresh': str(refresh),
                    'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                })
            else:
                # Log authentication failure
                logging.warning('Authentication failed - user is not authenticated.')
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Authentication Failed'}, status=401)
        except Exception as e:
            # Log any exceptions that occur during the process
            logging.error('Error during SAML2 processing: %s', str(e), exc_info=True)
            # Return a JSON response indicating an internal error
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}, status=500)
        finally:
            logging.info("FINALLY .................")

